# import date data from excel file to database using maatwebsite excel / laravel

Tags: excel, laravel

I'm trying to import data from excel file to database using `maatwebsite excel package`,

I'm using the following code :

```
namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use App\Models\Casting;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Auth;

class ProjectsImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow,WithValidation


{


     use Importable;
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
public function model(array $row)
    {
 
  $casting = new Casting();
  $casting->date_naissance = Date::excelToTimestamp($row['date_naissance']);

}

}
```

But doens't work , I get the following error :

```
"message": "Class 'PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Spreadsheet\\Shared\\Date' not found",
```

If you have any idea please help !

Answer (score 1):

When you use `dd()` on the date column from Excel you'll see that the data comes parsed as a number WITHOUT ANY SEPARATORS. The lack of separators is what brings about the challenge as your database will be expecting data in DATE format but you will be trying to update/create a record with an integer.

SOLUTION

You can use the [PHP Carbon Extension for Date and Time](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) to convert Excel date format into PHP date format.

Simply go through the documentation and you should be up and running in no time.

Comment: thank you for your answer , but the problme in in the `Class 'PhpOffice\\PhpSpreadsheet\\Spreadsheet\\Shared\\Date` not found

Comment: Hope you came right. Have been away a bit from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me in latest version of maatwebsite excel/laravel package.

[image]

```
$excel_date = $row[13]; //Your row line date that is : 3/17/2022
$uniq_date = ($excel_date - 25569) * 86400;
$date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $uniq_date);

dd($date);
```

Output : "2022-03-17 00:00:00"